# ASP.NET MVC 'SelectListItem' has no key defined Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET **individual user accounts** implementation and tried to add a DropDownList in the Register View so that the user can choose the city where he is from. I get the following error:
 *'SelectListItem' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. SelectListItems: EntityType: EntitySet 'SelectListItems' is based on type 'SelectListItem' that has no keys defined.*

In **RegisterViewModel** I added the following:

```
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select City!")]
  [Display(Name = "City")]
  public int CityId { get; set; }
  public List<SelectListItem> Cities { get; set; }
```

**View**:

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CityId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CityId", Model.Cities, "Select city", new { @class = "form-control" })
     </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

**GET** method:

```
public ActionResult Register()
 {
        var model = new RegisterViewModel();
        model.Cities = new List<SelectListItem>();
        SqlConnection con = //here is the connection string;
        string query = "SELECT * FROM City";
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
                {  
                   var city = new SelectListItem { Text = reader["Name"].ToString(), Value = reader["Id"].ToString() };
                   model.Cities.Add(city);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Eroare baza de date" + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

            return View(model);
}
```

And finally, the **POST** method

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               model.Cities = new List<SelectListItem>();
               int  cityId = model.CityId;
               var user = new ApplicationUser 
                    { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, CityId = cityId};
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. When are you getting the error ? when you load the page ? (GET action) ?

Comment: after i complete the form and press the submit button

Comment: if `ModelState.IsValid` returns `false`, you need to reload `model.Cities` collection before returning to the same view( which uses this collection to build the SELECT element).

Comment: I found the error, in IdentityModels inside the ApplicationUser class I added "public List<SelectListItem> Cities { get; set; }", which was incorrect

Comment: That is why you use view models :)

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.CityId, Model.Cities, "Select city", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

instead of this

`@Html.DropDownList("CityId", Model.Cities, "Select city", new { @class = "form-control"` })